# D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows-8, directx, windows-8.1

I am trying to create a dx11 device using D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain on Windows 8.1.

This was previously working on Windows 8 before I installed 8.1. However now the device creation fails when I pass the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag.

The enum documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476107(v=vs.85).aspx states that you need D3D11_1SDKLayers.dll installed but shouldn't this be installed already as part of the Windows 8 SDK?

I've even tried re installing the Windows 8 SDK but this hasn't helped. Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the Windows 8.1 SDK Layers (which are used when you pass the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG) requires that the Windows 8.1 SDK be installed on your system.  The Windows 8 SDK Layers (found in the Windows 8 SDK) are not compatible with 8.1.

You can find the 8.1 SDK on the link below.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=294834

Also, the Windows Graphics development team closely monitors the MSDN Forum "Building Windows Store games with DirectX", which can be found at:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-us/home?category=windowsapps%2Cwindowsapps81preview

So feel free to use that as a resource if you need help.